# Using Dumpyourphoto photo hosting via C#

Tags: c#, photo

I am currently trying to make a simple photo upload function that will upload a screenshot that I took. I found this website dumpyourphoto.com but I don't really understand how to do it in C#. Can anyone guide me through this?

Basically all I need is to upload a screenshot photo up to the server and hopefully it will return me a url to that photo. From there on, I will upload this URL up to a OpenShift database that I already set up and upload it as a text and store the link in the database.

Right. Thanks Simon for the question. I realised I didn't put much details up.

So basically I took a screenshot using kinect and this is the function that I am using.

```
private void btn_ss_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // create a png bitmap encoder which knows how to save a .png file
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

        // create frame from the writable bitmap and add to encoder
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(this.colorBitmap));

        string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh'-'mm'-'ss", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

        string myPhotos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectSnapshot-" + time + ".png");

        // write the new file to disk
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                encoder.Save(fs);
            }

            this.ss_dis.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Screenshot has been taken.", path);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            this.ss_dis.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Failed to take Screenshot.", path);
        }
    }
```

The part that I am struggling is that I have never really dealt with web activities such as HttpWebRequest functions before and the website shows xml and json. I have a slight idea of how to do it but I am not too sure. 
This is the link to the developer api.
http://www.dumpyourphoto.com/information/api

Update: I tried to work things out myself but I am stuck at this last part. I don't know how to attach the bytearray and key to the HttpWebRequest.

```
 private byte[] imgToByteArray(string _FileName)
    {
        byte[] _buffer = null;

        try
        {

            System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
            System.IO.BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream);

            long _TotalByte = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName).Length;
            _buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes((Int32)_TotalByte);

            _FileStream.Close();
            _FileStream.Dispose();
            _BinaryReader.Close();
         }
        catch(Exception _Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
        }

        return _buffer;
    }
```

This is the Image to ByteArray function.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string imgPath = "C:\\KinectSnapshot-04-46-14.png";
        string key = "1d533e9033f9d5b9b509055d8a00932aaf1ace7f";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.dumpyourphoto.com/api/upload_photo/xml");
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "KinectSnapshot-" + "03-38-28" + ".png");

        byte[] img = imgToByteArray(path);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = img.Length;
        using(Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            dataStream.Write(img, 0, img.Length);

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) 
        using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            string responseResults = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseResults);
        }
 }
```

Update: This is where I am currently. I have 2 problems left. I don't know where to attach the key file and the title of the uploaded picture. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

I would really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: What have you tried? Anything? The API on their website shows you what needs to be done. What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

You would use HttpWebRequest to make a POST request using the methods listed in their API. Is there something specific you're struggling with?

Comment: Yes, sorry but I am still quite new at this. Looking at the API documents, I am guessing I need a bytearray of the photo, a key and a title. So far this is what I did. I converted a the image to byte array and I am trying to upload this file using the HttpWebRequest. I set the method to post already. Problem is I am not very clear how to attach the key and the bytearray into HttpWebRequest.

Comment: This really helped alot! But I just have 2 small problems left >.<

Comment: I have no idea where to attach the key and the Title of the photo.

Comment: you'd add it like key=thekey&title=thetitle&data=bytes - have a look at how to create the form data. MSDN docs will help here - it's just a POST, as if you were submitting a form.